# OR operator in MVC URL pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm writing an MVC route and i was wondering, can i use something like an OR operator in it?

Something like this, where my Urls can either start with "shop/" or with "articles/"?

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "shop|articles/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Store", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Assuming you've read http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs, your question should be "how to build regular expression that accepts one of two strings"... If you don't know about that feature - than this question is duplicate of something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767625/mvc-routes-with-regular-expression

Comment: I think in this case @AlexeiLevenkov, this question does not need to be changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a route constraint where you specify the valid values separated by pipes.

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{page}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Store", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
   constraints: new { page = "shop|articles" });
```

Comment: Thanks Henk. I have seen many examples, but somehow none of them showed me anything about constraints.